# Python(Django) - Convert URL from post to a embed YouTube IFrame

Tags: python, django, iframe, youtube, embed

Basically what I trying to achive is to find the URL in the post, for example if I post this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example
```

It will be looking like this: 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

[image: YouTube Player]

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class NewsFeed_Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120) 
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

post.html:

```
{% extends "Feed/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="card">
  <h2 class="text-info">{{newsfeed_articles.title}}</h2>
  <h6 class="text-info">{{newsfeed_articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i:s"}}</h6>
  <p>{{newsfeed_articles.post|safe|linebreaks}}<p>
  <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the code to convert YouTube URLs to YouTube Embeds:

```py
import re

def convert_ytframe(text):
  _yt = re.compile(r'(https?://)?(www\.)?((youtu\.be/)|(youtube\.com/watch/?\?v=))([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)', re.I)
  _frame_format = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
  
  def replace(match):
    groups = match.groups()
    return _frame_format.format(groups[5])
  return _yt.sub(replace, text)
```

Here's working example you can test it yourself: [repl.it/@themisir/AromaticAvariciousMarketing](https://replit.com/@themisir/AromaticAvariciousMarketing) 
Also, you could test Regular Expression here: [regex101.com/r/97yhSH/1](https://regex101.com/r/97yhSH/1)

## UPDATE

The code was simplified.

```py
import re

yt_link = re.compile(r'(https?://)?(www\.)?((youtu\.be/)|(youtube\.com/watch/?\?v=))([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)', re.I)
yt_embed = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'

def convert_ytframe(text):
  return yt_link.sub(lambda match: yt_embed.format(match.groups()[5]), text)
```